# When does the time for fajr prayer end?

Tags: salat, time, fajr

I want to know when does the fajr waqt end.

Say if sunrise is at 7.30 AM. Then how do we calculate the last minute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fajr time will last long till the sun-rises.

> It was narrated from Abdullah bin Amr (RA) that the Prophet (PBUH)
>   said, “The time for Zuhr is so long as Asr has not come. The time for
>   Asr is so long as the sun has not turned yellow. The time for Maghrib
>   is so long as the twilight has not disappeared. The time for Isha is
>   so long as half of the night has not passed. The time for Fajr is so
>   long as the sun has not risen.”- **Muslim, Vol.2, 1386**.

If you have time to pray atleast one rakat of fajr prayer before sun-rise, then pray Fajr,

> It is narrated By Abu Huraira : Allah's Apostle said, "If anyone of
>   you can get one Rak'a of the 'Asr prayer before sunset, he should
>   complete his prayer. If any of you can get one Rak'a of the Fajr
>   prayer before sunrise, he should complete his prayer."- [Bukhari
>   Volume 001, Book 010, Hadith 531.](http://www.hadithcollection.com/sahihbukhari/43-Sahih%20Bukhari%20Book%2010.%20Times%20of%20the%20Prayers/1109-sahih-bukhari-volume-001-book-010-hadith-number-531.html)

And

> It is also Narrated By Abu Huraira : Allah's Apostle said, "Whoever
>   could get one Rak'a of a prayer, (in its proper time) he has got the
>   prayer."- [Bukhari Volume 001, Book 010, Hadith 554.](http://www.hadithcollection.com/sahihbukhari/43-Sahih%20Bukhari%20Book%2010.%20Times%20of%20the%20Prayers/1086-sahih-bukhari-volume-001-book-010-hadith-number-554.html)

Comment: Can anyone please clarify (according to scholars) one raka' to start (and then rest of raka') before its finished or just one raka' like we do in witr (last witr of single raka')? Please ask if my question isn't clear

Comment: @mkhan3189, If you have a question, please ask a [new question](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) :)

Answer (score 1):

The time until which Fajr prayer can be said without deeming it qaza (end) is before sunrise, which in case of your example is 7:30 AM.

Answer (score 0):

The salat of Fajr starts when (True) Fajr comes in, up until the sun starts rises.  Once the sun has risen, the time of the salat ends, and so from that time you would have to make it up.  So qaza (قضاء) time would be, if sun rise is at 7:30, after the sun has fully risen.

For further information see [this (Arabic)](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/52278)