# What time does Fajr end exactly?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

I always see daylight before the actual Sun rise time, also I'm aware that it is prohibited to pray during sun rise.

So what time does end (or how many minutes before predicted sun rise times)?

Comment: possible duplicate http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10000/what-would-be-end-time-of-fajr-before-it-gets-qaza